# How to create an adjacency matrix by counting number of co-appearance in a dataframe?

Tags: python, r, network-programming

I want to create a network in R. I have a dataframe looks like this. Say Alex has an apple and a banana, Brian has two apple and a Peach, and John has...

```r
Alex    Apple
Alex    Banana
Alex    Kiwi
Brian   Apple
Brian   Apple
Brian   Peach
John    Kiwi
John    Peach
John    Banana
Chris   Melon
Chris   Apple
...
```

I want use this dataframe to create a non-directed network that use fruit as nodes. If one person has both two different fruits, say John has a peach and kiwi, then there is a edge between node peach and kiwi. the weight of the edge is how many people has both these fruits(nodes).

I'm think about creating an adjacency matrix first, but don't know how to do it. If you have a better idea about creating a different network based on this dataframe, please give me a hint.

Comment: Self-join on person, filter out cases where fruit.x and fruit.y are the same. This gives  you all pairs. Sort within rows so that fruit.x is always alphabetically before fruit.y. Aggregate by fruit.x and fruit.y, the number of rows is the weight. Do you really not care if the solution is R or Python?

Comment: I prefer using R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP does not have a desired output, assuming that dupes are to be removed, here is an option using `combn` in `data.table`:

```
edges <- unique(DT)[, if (.N > 1L) transpose(combn(Fruit, 2L, simplify=FALSE)), Person][, 
    .N, .(V1, V2)]
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges)
set_edge_attr(g, "weight", value=edges$N)
plot(g)
#to check weights, use get.data.frame(g)
```

`edges`:

```
       V1     V2 N
1:  Apple Banana 1
2:  Apple   Kiwi 1
3: Banana   Kiwi 1
4:  Apple  Peach 1
5:   Kiwi  Peach 1
6:   Kiwi Banana 1
7:  Peach Banana 1
8:  Melon  Apple 1
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Person Fruit
Alex    Apple
Alex    Banana
Alex    Kiwi
Brian   Apple
Brian   Apple
Brian   Peach
John    Kiwi
John    Peach
John    Banana
Chris   Melon
Chris   Apple
Andrew  Apple")
```

Comment: Thanks, this might be exactly what I want.

Comment: What about the case that if there is one person having only one fruit (eg. Andrew has an Apple) in the table?

Comment: @DeliangWang you can check using `if (.N > 1L)` before creating the combinations